# Android Location Listener not updating in the time I'm telling

Tags: android, location, timing, locationlistener

I want the LocationListener on Android to ask for update every 5 seconds

I am doing this:

```
    locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(high.getName(), (long) 5000, 0,
    UpdL1 = new LocationListener() {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // do something here to save this new location
    if (location != null) {
        //
        updateARLoc(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        //
        if(!creada){
        locMgr.removeUpdates(UpdL1);
        }
        } else {
        }    
  }
```

I am telling it to update every **5000** miliseconds, that's 5 seconds. But it keeps updating all the time. The logcat is telling me that is updating like every 500 miliseconds. (Every "A" printed is an update from the listener)

```
    09-14 14:57:29.998: INFO/info(3456): A
    09-14 14:57:30.018: INFO/info(3456): A
    09-14 14:57:30.918: INFO/info(3456): A
    09-14 14:57:30.928: INFO/info(3456): A
    09-14 14:57:31.988: INFO/info(3456): A
    09-14 14:57:31.998: INFO/info(3456): A
    09-14 14:57:32.958: INFO/info(3456): A
    09-14 14:57:32.988: INFO/info(3456): A
    09-14 14:57:33.948: INFO/info(3456): A
    09-14 14:57:33.948: INFO/info(3456): A
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)

Right under parameters for the requestLocationUpdates method it states:

"the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value."

requestLocationUpdates() makes the droid's GPS try to get a fix on your location.  While trying to get the fix, your locationlistener could get tons of location updates.

After receiving the location updates, then the GPS should turn off for the amount of time you specified in mintime parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As you can find in android documentation:

*The frequency of notification may be controlled using the minTime and minDistance parameters. If minTime is greater than 0, the LocationManager **could potentially rest for minTime milliseconds between location updates to conserve power**. If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcasted if the device moves by minDistance meters. To obtain notifications as frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0.*

In other words, if your device do not need to save power it will send update when it wants.

Furthermore, you've set the minDistance parameter to 0 which means you want an update every 0 meters (so as often as possible).

Comment: I don't think that's what the documentation is saying.  It's saying that the GPS will not send you updates for x number of millis AFTER a fix has been achieved.